# knockout doesn't update html after get data from ajax

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I bind list of data to HTML, in each list has button for get details by ajax. I want to bind callback data to member of model, After ajax call back, object have data, view received (  ko.toJSON(d, null, 2))object. But HTML doesn't update data.
I don't know what is wrong. please help. Thank you.

Html:

```
<section id="lists">
    <article class="todoList">
        <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
          <!--  <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: message"></span></p>-->
            <p>xxx</p>
        </script>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <span class="contentarea" data-bind="text: message"></span>
                    <button data-bind="click: $parent.evClick.bind($data)">Get details</button>
                    <button data-bind="click: detail">Ajax-Get</button>
                    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: d.message"></span></p>
                    <div style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px #ff6a00;" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(d, null, 2)"></div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</section>
```

Full code here.
http://jsfiddle.net/wuttipat/sc8fX/12/

Comment: The jsFiddle doesn't exactly work: you forgot to add references to Knockout and jQuery. I changed your fiddle (see http://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/sc8fX/2/) and I can see in my Firefox JS Console that it's trying to load data, but can't (because the URL doesn't exist of course).

Comment: What I mean by that, is that it would be interesting if you could provide a jsFiddle that only has the problem you're experiencing. So, replace the code doing the ajax call by hard coded data (in the form you're getting from your ajax call). This way, people can actually test it and see what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, I just add mock up data to http://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/sc8fX/2/
when you click Ajax-get, object toJSon will bind to div but <span data-bind="text: d.message"></span> doesn't get update.

Comment: But when use only d (data-bind="text: d.message") It show me an object.

Comment: After you modified the jsfiddle, please click on 'Update' and provide us that URL (it will have changed an no longer be /petermorlion/sc8fX/2).

Comment: Hi, this is an updated. http://jsfiddle.net/wuttipat/sc8fX/14/

Comment: Okay, and what do you expect to happen? When I click on 'Ajax-Get', the JSON is put in the box below it. This is correct with the code: `text: ko.toJSON(d, null, 2)`

Comment: Yes, It seem view received object from model, But after ajax callback, I want to bind the call back object to Html (<p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: d.message"></span></p>). In this case d.message doesn't update.

Comment: You're going to have to remove all unnecessary code from your jsFiddle (get details button? antiForgeryToken? there's an unused template in there etc etc etc). This is too hard to help efficiently. To me, the code works fine. Ajax-Get returns data, the view is update.

Comment: I just removed some code are not relate with the issue now. http://jsfiddle.net/wuttipat/sc8fX/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
<div data-bind="with: d">
    <span data-bind="text: message"></span>
```

Because data-bind="with: d" create scope for binding context when you use data-bind="text: message" inside it will reference to parent binding context in this case mean d.

Full code here : http://jsfiddle.net/sc8fX/74/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out (after cleaning up the fiddle some more). You're binding is

```
text: d.message
```

But it should be

```
text: message
```

Because `d` is the context of your binding. So you're actually trying to bind to `d.d.message` which doesn't exist. Replacing it with `text: message` seemed to work, no?

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petermorlion/sc8fX/56/).

Comment: Hi, In my object text: message is list item's message. It will bind when we apply binding, But text: d.message is a message from ajax callback object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue posted on knockout document.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html